# E: Couldn't find package logkeys

Tags: ubuntu, packages

I am trying to install logkeys but I am having some trouble. 
I went to system and checked everything in third party but still no luck. Can someone please help and tell me how to get this package so that my install runs as it shou

Comment: `logkeys` should be in the universe repository. It is on my machine (Oneiric). What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 2):

As [user55325 pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/401411/e-couldnt-find-package-logkeys/425555#comment456330_401411), logkeys is in the universe repository. Make sure you have the option to download and install packages from universe enabled.

Open software-center. Go to Edit menu --> Open software sources and check *Universe* option.

[image]

After checking the option, run the following commands to install `logkeys`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install logkeys
```